# Ideas on how to copy something from 1 application to another

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I am looking for ideas but what I want to know is that I am creating multiple exams. Now lets say I have 2 exams, I create the questions and answers for exam 1 and the submit the form, I then get onto exam 2, now in exam 2 there will be some different questions but there could also be the same questions from exam 1 but in a different order.

What I want to know is that what if the best way so that when the user is creating exam 2, he can open up something and be able to copy the questions and answers from exam 1 into exam 2 when he wants to do that?

I was thinking using a second database (a backup database) to store all questions from exam 1 and then somehow be able to copy some of these questions and answers from exam 1 into exam 2 by one question at a time.

The reason I am thinking of using a backup Database is because I want all of the details to be stored in the proper database after everything is finished (if power goes out or router is turned off during the middle of creating exams, I do not want my proper database to store in hald the data so thats why I want to store it in a backup database and only store it in full database after everything is complete)

The layout of my questions and answers is that a question is in a textarea and the answers are from A -Z button where the user can select as many buttons as they wish?

Thanks

Comment: Why use a backup database? If question 1 on Exam 1 matches, just display it on exam 2. Store everything in a database, query it and populate matches

Comment: OK then I won't do backup database, but when you said do a query, what can I query on, Keywords in a question? Also question 1 in exam 1 could be question 4 in exam 2, is this possible?

Comment: The question would be the same, so you'd identify it with a unique id. Query the question's id

Comment: Ok last question, if you have 3 exams, question 1 in exam 1 is different to question 1 in exam 2, then how do you query question id? unless you state exam id and then question id, that could work could it?

Comment: If the questions are different, they're different. I'm not following what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The way I have set up my database, question id is question number. So if question 1 in exam 1 is what is 2+2 and question 1 in exam 2 is what is the capital of france, they are both different questions but they are both question 1 but for different exams. So if you want to search for a previous question (what is 2+2) its best to first search exam number which 1 and then question number which is 1 to find that question. But I need to do it so that if I can select an exam number, it shows all of the questions in that exam number and then I pick the question I want to add in the latest exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SQL database you can make 2 tables like:

```
 Exams(id, examname, description)
 Questions(id, examid, question, answer)
```

If needed, join them, or get questions from certain exams like:

```
SELECT * FROM Questions
JOIN Exams
ON Questions.examid = Exams.id
```

You can reuse questions, by readding them with another examid, or by adding another examid to the examid with a delimiter.

Comment: you can add keywords, questionnr to the table Questions - or add questions to Exams, and add there the questions in the right order (like 3,7,1,5) and then join that with questions.